# Rearrange UIView Subviews if a Subview is removed in Auto Layout

Tags: ios, uiview, autolayout, subviews, layoutsubviews

I am in a need of implementing a drag and drop controller in Full-Auto Layout environment.
I have achieved the dragging and dropping successfully, but the issue is if I drag a subview from another view the other related subviews behave weirdly, 
as an example the subviews are laid out horizontally in scrollview are related to each other, so if I remove a subview the other views should rearrange them self automatically.

Regards,
Dhanesh.

Answer (score 0):

when you doing the design part of xib uncheck the autolayout.
After completing the designing then go towards to autolayout and arrange the view using   constraint adding.

Comment: How this will affect the runtime operations needed to rearrange the views? Also, I am developing a generic controller for drag and drop so that I can use it from anywhere, irrespective of the .xibs.

Comment: u need to fix the one view and adding your controller on that view.

Comment: Hmm Interesting, but i'd rather go with Generic approach so that I dont have to take care of the xib and the size on which my controller is used. Any ways thanks.